# The name 'someControl' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some weird problem with asp.net controls.

I am editing a (previously) working page, but when I add a new control, and try to run it, it says:

> The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context

Also when I rename a working control, on both markup, and code-behind file, it will also give this error for this control.

I did read something about deleting the designer file, and "convert to web application", but I don't have any designer file, nor the option to "convert to web application.".

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: Some example:

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBank" style="width: 227px;">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" style="width: 227px;">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
if (ddlBank.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    displayMessageBar("Error", "Je dient eerst een bank op te geven.", "error");
    return;
}

if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    displayMessageBar("Error", "Je dient eerst een bank op te geven.", "error");
    return;
}
```

The error message my IDE gives:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Did you check if your controls are declared as public/protected properties or fields in your codbehind. If so, you will have to declare the new ones the same way, and rename the properties/fields of the controls you need to rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

It seems that some colleague added another page, pointing to the same code-behind file.
That worked fine, until I changed something.

Let's hope someone else can use this information.